# Watch selected next select

Tags: css, select, radio-button

When selecting an item, the one I select is not selected.
The following is highlighted(2 select), but the value (value="1")of the selected.
How to make the selected one select?
css

```
.cc-selector input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0 !important;
  outline-offset: 0 !important;
}

.yellow {
  background-image: url(1.png);
}

.orange {
  background-image: url(2.png);
}

.red {
  background-image: url(3.png);
}

.fair {
  background-image: url(4.png);
}

.cc-selector input:active + .priorities-cc {
  opacity: .9;
}

.cc-selector input:checked + .priorities-cc {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.priorities-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.priorities-cc:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}

/* Extras */
a:visited {
  color: #888
}

a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}
```

html

```
<div class="cc-selector">
          <input id="yellow" class="priorities-cc yellow" for="yellow" type="radio" value="1" name="color">
          <input id="orange" class="priorities-cc orange" for="orange" type="radio" value="2" name="color">
          <input id="red" class="priorities-cc red" for="red" type="radio" value="3" name="color">
          <input id="fair" class="priorities-cc fair" for="fair" type="radio" value="4" name="color">
        </div>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find you solution here
https://jsfiddle.net/d1yn7pat/

```
/* Removed + .priorities-cc */
 .cc-selector input:checked{
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Sounds great. Cheers mate !!